# Can we multiply power series of two analytic functions term by term?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions analytic at $a\in\mathbb{C}$, with the following power series expansions $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-a)^n$$
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-a)^n$$
Is it true that the power series expansion of $fg$ at $a$ is
$$f(z)g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ib_{n-i})(z-a)^n$$

Comment: That is, you are looking for the proof of Cauchy product formula?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One elegant way to see this is the following. Call $z-a= e^{i w}$, for some $w \in \mathbb C$. Then the power series expansion takes the following form:

$$\hat f(w) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{iwn}, \quad \hat g(w) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n e^{iwn}.$$

Therefore, $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of the sequence $(a_n)$ and $\hat g$ is the Fourier transform of the sequence $(b_n)$. But it is well-known that the Fourier transform of the convolution is the product of the Fourier transforms. Therefore

$$\hat f(w)\hat g(w)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a * b)_n e^{iwn} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}\right)e^{iwn} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}\right)(z-a)^n,$$

which is the formula you are looking for.

Comment: And is the resulting power series analytic in the common region of convergence?

Comment: Yes. If at least one of the two series you multiply is absolutely convergent (both, in your case), then the resulting product series converges at the points where the original series converge (see Mertens' theorem). Since the resulting series is a power series, then you have uniform convergence and so analycity.

Comment: This is nice, but I think that it is somewhat circular: to prove that the Fourier transform of a product equals the convolution one essentially does the same algebra that is needed to prove that the product of power series is given by the Cauchy product. Actually, I would rather use this observation in the other way round: given the Cauchy product formula, use it to show that Fourier transform of product is convolution. It seems more natural.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I agree with you. In fact my aim was not to provide a proof, but rather a way to see the equality from another point of view.